# Setting PYTHONPATH with bash script and running nosetests

Tags: python, bash, nose

I have the following script that sets a clean `PYTHONPATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the directory the script is in
DIR=$(cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd)

$ Walk up to root of branch dir
DIR=$DIR/../../..

PYTHONPATH=$DIR/module1
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$DIR/module2
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$DIR/module3
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$DIR/module4
export PYTHONPATH
```

This script is supposed to be run in tandem with a nosetest command to allow tests to import all the necessary modules when needed without any issues:

`./path/to/script/PythonPath.sh && nosetests <tons of other arguments>`

However, when I run the above command, I get an `ImportError` on one of the modules stating that it does not exist. I have added an `echo` statement at the end of the script to help debug and the `PYTHONPATH` is exactly as it should be. I have also tried setting the `PYTHONPATH` manually and can't seem reproduce the same issue.

Comment: So it works when you set it manually?

Comment: @vicg Yes, that is correct.

Comment: subshell can't influence the parent shell, just run your test inside of the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set environment variables in bash that way.  The script ends up running in its own process, setting the environment there and not reaching back into yours.  In this case you could `source` or `.` the script to have it affect your current environment:

```
source ./path/to/script/PythonPath.sh && nosetests <tons of other arguments>
```

or

```
. ./path/to/script/PythonPath.sh && nosetests <tons of other arguments>
```

Also, you have extra quotes that aren't helpful and at least 1 line missing a comment character.  Here's a script with those fixes:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the directory the script is in
DIR=$(cd $( dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} ) && pwd)

# Walk up to root of branch dir
DIR=$DIR/../../..

PYTHONPATH=$DIR/module1
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$DIR/module2
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$DIR/module3
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$DIR/module4
export PYTHONPATH
```

When I source that file I get:

```
/tmp/scratch$ . PythonPath.sh
/tmp/scratch$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/tmp/scratch/../../../module1:/tmp/scratch/../../../module2:/tmp/scratch/../../../module3:/tmp/scratch/../../../module4
```

Comment: When I run `source` or `.` on the script, the echo statement on `PYTHONPATH` reproduces a long string of all the directories and Python files I referenced to in the script rather than the usual syntax (i.e. `/dir/module1:/dir/module2`). Also, the issue still persists.

Comment: Do you have spaces in any of the directory or module names?  Quoting will be very important if you do

Comment: No, they are either camel cased or separated with underscores.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the value of `PYTHONPATH` after you sourced the file?  I'm not able to recreate what you're describing.

Comment: Sure.  `Directory1/ thisIsAModule.py* anotherDirectory/ module2.py* configs/`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to that problem or not, but you do have some syntax errors in your script as posted as well, I'm going to edit my post to have a cleaned up version

Comment: I fixed the syntax errors and am still having the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80391/discussion-between-eric-renouf-and-ilostmyspoon).

Comment: I found the issue! I had a custom function `cd` in my `.bash_rc` that runs both `cd` and `ls`. After removing it, the script works as intended. Thanks for your help.